# Resetting form controls after action in Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, data-binding

Need a bit of help with [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/59WEnMAY0BKcX4P0Hvy8?p=preview). I am trying to get Angular to reset value of my input box after add control is invoked. This is kind of important when it comes to drop down select boxes. I want to be able to clear what user has selected after the option is pushed to a collection.

I also seems to have an issue with `user.fName` updating whatever I previously added to the `users` array but it's probably related to the above.

Also can you see what I am doing wrong with `ng-show`?

html

```
<div ng-controller="UserController" name="form">
  <div ng-show="form.fName.$touched">Hello {{ user.fName }}</div>
  <input type="text" name="fName" ng-model="user.fName">
  <a ng-click="addUser(user)">Add</a>
    <br>
  <div ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user }}</div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function UserController($scope) {
  //$scope.user = {
  //    fName: "Joe",
  //    lName: "Doe"
  //};
  $scope.users = [];
  $scope.addUser = function (user) {
    if($scope.users.indexOf(user) === -1){
      $scope.users.push(user);
    } else {
      // trigger error/notification message
      console.log(user, ' already added');
    }
    user = {}; //clear user
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngModel` will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the expression on the current scope. If the property doesn't already exist on this scope, it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

You are currently not using the scoped property in your click action but a copy that is passed as a parameter. Change `user` to `$scope.user` in your `addUser` method

Note: your object comparison to identify already added users won't work as you always create new objects that will never match. Change it to some different comparison method like comparing the fName properties.

html

```
<div ng-controller="UserController" name="form">
  <div ng-show="form.fName.$touched">Hello {{ user.fName }}</div>
  <input type="text" name="fName" ng-model="user.fName">
  <a ng-click="addUser()">Add</a>
    <br>
  <div ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user }}</div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function UserController($scope) {
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.addUser = function () {
        if($scope.users.indexOf($scope.user) === -1){
          $scope.users.push($scope.user);
        } else {
          // will never match as indexOf() will always return -1
          console.log($scope.user, ' already added');
        }
        $scope.user = {}; //clear user
    };
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/N5FXJdWRl42YrVwJsUuR?p=preview

As for your ng-show question: $touched was introduced in AngularJS 1.3 and you're referencing AngularJS 1.2.x in your Plunker code.

Comment: That definitely did the trick with clearing my input box. Thank you for a prompt reply.

Comment: Please see my edit at the end for your ng-show question

Comment: ``if($scope.users.indexOf($scope.user) === -1) { }`` was really supposed to be used for select boxes. It looks like I was doing something silly with ``ng-show``. I will amend my ways. Thank you for the help. I wish I could up vote your answer again :)

Comment: I suppose it is worth mention that ``ng-show="form.fName.$touched"`` works only in the context of ``<form name="form">``. At least that's the conclusion I reached after playing around with it for a while.